# Location Access in Android 11

Tags: android, android-location, android-background

Google documentation states:

*If you request foreground
location and background location
at the same time, the system  throws an exception.*

Now, suppose I want my app to be able to access location when (i) the device is locked (ii) the device is unlocked and the app is in foreground. Is it possible in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-location-access-runtime):

> Even if several features in your app require location access, it's
> likely that only some of them require background location access.
> Therefore, it's recommended that your app performs incremental
> requests for location permissions, asking for foreground location
> access and then background location access. By performing incremental
> requests, you give users more control and transparency because they
> can better understand which features in your app need background
> location access.
>
> The process for performing incremental requests is as follows:
>
> 1. At first, your app should guide users to the features that require
>    foreground location access, such as the "share location" feature in
>    Figure 1 or the "show current location" feature in Figure 2.
>
> It's recommended that you disable user access to features that require
> background location access until your app has foreground location
> access.
>
> 2. At a later time, when the user explores functionality that requires
>    background location access, you can request background location
>    access.

So the short answer is **yes**. You can use both foreground and background locations in the app, just don't ask for both at the same time.

Comment: did you test this?

Comment: No, I'm not working at something similar at the moment. Why, did you encounter any related problems?

Comment: Tomorrow will start work on this as well, wanted to know if it's based on documentation or on actual dev testing

Comment: Just documentation. Good luck with your project! Perhaps you should ask the author of the question if he managed to make it work.

Comment: If you think this question is going to help others with similar doubts, kindly upvote it.